# Thread.currentThread() performance

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, jvm

I have Runnable queue that invokes one by one in specified thread.

```kotlin
val queue = LinkedBlockingQueue<() -> Unit>()

val queueThread = thread {
  while(true)
    queue.take().invoke()
}
```

Also I have function that adds Runnable and wait for it to complete.

```kotlin
fun invokeOnQueueThread(toInvoke: () -> Unit){
  if(Thread.currentThread() == queueThread)
    toInvoke()
  else {
    queue.offer(toInvoke)
    // Some waiting code...
  }
}
```

I test if current thread is already inside my queue's thread to prevent unnecessary locking itself.

So, the question is:

Will `Thread.currentThread()` cause performance issues if I call this code very, very often?

Comment: Have you tried measuring the performance of calling `Thread.currentThread()` in isolation yet?

Comment: @boneill I haven't, because it depends on OS implementation. So I want to know an "avarage" load

Comment: Performance must be measured and not guessed upon.

Comment: If it is performance-sensitive code, make sure you have some benchmarks in place. JMH is a great tool with out-of-the-box support for great profilers like perf. This will help you to figure out where time is actually being spent.

Comment: Why would it be a problem for the thread that serves the queue to add new tasks to the queue? That's actually a pretty normal design pattern (not that I know the name of it.) OTOH, maybe there's some other reason why you want to treat that case specially, and perform the task _before_ everything else that's already in the queue, but if so, then IMO that's a bit of a code smell just _because_ you treat it as a special case.

Comment: P.S., I don't actually _know_ what `Thread.currentThread()` does—it apparently is a `native` method in OpenJDK—but I would be surprised if it was not a system call, and I would be surprised if the system call (on most OSs) did anything more than return the value of some kernel variable without `yield()`ing to any other thread.

Comment: @SolomonSlow *"that's a bit of a code smell just because you treat it as a special case"* - that's pretty much what every reactive framework does (purposely!)

Comment: @SolomonSlow *"I would be surprised if it was not a system call"* - It isn't. Switching to kernel and back for a basic TLS access would be an unacceptable overkill. Furthermore, `Thread.currentThread` is a not a "real" native call - it's rather a JVM intrinsic method that is translated by JIT to just a couple of load instructions.

Comment: @apangin, Re, "code smell." I guess I've had my wrist slapped too many times for "premature optimization" in application-specific code. It's been a long time (several decades) since I worked on library code that was going to end up in thousands of applications. It's a different mind set.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JDK itself relies on the performance of `Thread.currentThread()`, as this method is widely used in the standard Java class library: specifically, in [`ThreadLocal.get`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/e54f26aa3d5d44264e052bc51d3d819a8da5d1e7/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java#L163), [`ReentrantLock.lock`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/e54f26aa3d5d44264e052bc51d3d819a8da5d1e7/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.java#L126) and in other java.util.concurrent primitives.

Although `Thread.currentThread()` is marked as a native method in OpenJDK, it is not a real JNI method, but rather a [JVM intrinsic](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/e54f26aa3d5d44264e052bc51d3d819a8da5d1e7/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/vm/annotation/IntrinsicCandidate.java#L31-L38). This means, JIT compiler replaces the call with a highly optimized machine code.

On most CPU architectures (x64, ARM, etc.) HotSpot JVM has a dedicated CPU register for holding a pointer to the current thread. Not a `java.lang.Thread`, but an internal VM structure representing a Java thread. In turn, this structure holds a reference to the corresponding `java.lang.Thread` object. So, in the JIT-compiled code, getting a reference to the current thread is just a single load from a structure pointed by a dedicated register.

E.g. on x64 the register R15 holds a pointer to the current VM thread while executing Java code, and `Thread.currentThread()` call is compiled to something like

```
  mov  0x280(%r15),%r11
```

Therefore calling `Thread.currentThread()` is not slower than reading a regular field, and should not be a performance issue.